# Is there a Data View of Email Content Tied to the Job Data View?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data-views

The [Data View for Job](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_job.htm&type=5) has an `EmailID` as one of the columns. Is there a Data View for Email that can be associated with the job using that `EmailID` column? Documentation of [Data Views](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5) doesn't have anything regarding email content.

The only other option I can think of is making "my own email data view" using AMPscript in the email at the time of send:

```
%%[ 
IF _messagecontext == "SEND" AND jobid > 0 THEN
set @EmailContent = HTTPGet(view_email_url)
InsertDE("Email_Data_View",
"JobID",jobid,
"SubscriberKey",_subscriberkey,
"EmailContent",@EmailContent
)
ENDIF
]%%
```

Has anyone done anything like this before? Any other implications with this? I imagine I can just keep the code in a Content Area and drop that in the Admin HTML Header.

Comment: there is not an email data view, you can use that email id and make an api call to the email object using soap

Comment: Are you looking to archive each and every send, or just the current HTML (prior to being processed) of the email id? Or something different?

Comment: Yes storying each and every send.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to store a copy of the sent email. This is a great question. There are several considerations with your proposed approach.

### 1. Send Performance

While all AMPscript calls to insert, update or delete data are [made in a single call, after all emails have been sent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ampscriptProcessing.htm), OMM will still check the DE used to perform the Insert when the email is sent (I assume to validate that the record can be inserted). I've noticed a significant performance issue, where if you have many records (like 1m+) in the DE used by the InsertDE function, then this can have a big impact on send performance and slow your send down to ~1k records per hour.

### 2. Database Performance

While you can create unbounded columns in Data Extension fields (e.g. not set a field length value), Marketing Cloud uses Microsoft SQL Server for Data Extensions. And [SQL Server has a row limit of 8,060 bytes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). Columns that don't fit within the limit are placed off-row, in a separate internal table. As a result, the platform has to execute multiple queries in order to return a single row for Data Extension records that exceed this row limit.

So if you store an entire HTML message in a single DE field, the platform has to make several queries to retrieve a single record (in order to retrieve all the separate fragments).

If you will only retrieve a single record (e.g. to display HTML on a CloudPage), then you won't really notice a performance impact, but if you need to query a large recordset, then you may experience issues.

### 3. Open Tracking

Just remember that when you retrieve the HTML using the `view_email_url`, this will count as an 'open'. So make sure you wrap your open tracking pixel in a conditional statement. For example:

```js
%%[ if _messagecontext != "VAWP" then ]%%
<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking"></custom>
%%[ endif ]%%
```

### My Recommended Approach

When I come across a requirement to store HTML at send time, I typically do the following:

1. Create a Send Log DE with a Retention Policy (like 1 month)
2. Add a nullable text field named to the Send Log named `view_email_url`
3. Add a nullable boolean field to the Send Log named `Processed` with a default value of `false`

When emails are sent, the VAWP link will automatically be added to the `view_email_url` field in your Send Log DE.

Then, either using a Script Activity and an Automation, **or** an external app which retrieves DE records using the Marketing Cloud API (I'd recommend the latter if you have a choice, so you can run this process this asynchronously), perform the following tasks:

1. Retrieve all records in the Send Log where `Processed` equals `false`
2. Next, get the HTML from the `view_email_url`
3. Store it (somewhere) and then update the `Processed` field to `true`.

I've tried using Script Activity in an Automation, but the process to retrieve the VAWP HTML using SSJS is slow, as you can only loop through records consecutively. I've found that I can't process more than 3,000 records at a time in a Script Activity (any longer and the Script takes more than 30 mins to run and times out).

Instead, I generally run this asynchronously from a Heroku app and store the HTML in [MongoDB GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) which is a more appropriate data store for this type of data.